# Getting Error While Adding Contacts to FreshSales CRM

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc

I am trying add new contacts to `Freshsales CRM` in my `Java Spring MVC Web Application`. I had added  the jar file needed for the FreshsalesAnalytics class in my project class path. Iam using the following code for adding contacts to fresh sales.

```
FreshsalesAnalytics freshsales = new FreshsalesAnalytics("URL", "TOKEN");
JSONObject newLead = new JSONObject();
newLead.put("First name", "John"); //Replace with first name of the user
newLead.put("Last name", "Doe"); //Replace with last name of the user
newLead.put("Email", "john.doe@example.com"); //Replace with email of the user
//newLead.put("fs_contact", true); if you want to create a contact
newLead.put("Alternate contact number", "98765432"); //Replace with custom field
JSONObject company = new JSONObject();
company.put("Name", "Example.com"); //Replace with company name
company.put("Website", "www.example.com"); //Replace with website of company
newLead.put("company", company);
String identifier = "john.doe@example.com"; //Replace with unique identifier
freshsales.identify(identifier, newLead);
```

But I am getting error in "`freshsales.identify(identifier, newLead);`". 
 In one support document I saw that we can use `"freshsales.set(identifier, newLead);"`, But here i cant be able to use `set` attribute.

I am getting "`The type org.json.JSONObject cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"` error in " freshsales.identify(identifier, newLead);"` code.
 How can i overcome this issue. Any help is highly appreciated.